# How to go through a string and delete a repeated word with Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace

I have this `string`:

```py
_str = '{"id": sa.Column("id", sa.Integer(), table=None, primary_key=True, nullable=False),"person": sa.Column("person", sa.String(length=40), table=None),"name": sa.Column("name", sa.String(length=40), table=None),"__tablename__": "departments"}'
```

And I want to delete each appearance of the word `table`, but even using `replace ('table', '')`, I can't delete it. I know there are similar issues, but they did not help in this case.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @SreeramTP, something like this `'{"id": sa.Column("id", sa.Integer(), primary_key=True, nullable=False),"person": sa.Column("person", sa.String(length=40)),"name": sa.Column("name", sa.String(length=40)),"__tablename__": "departments"}'`, the same string but without `table=None`

Comment: does this server your purpose : _str.replace(", table=None", "") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `re` to do a `sub` instead, as that catches more broader cases I would say:

```py
import re
_str = '{"id": sa.Column("id", sa.Integer(), table=None, primary_key=True, nullable=False),"person": sa.Column("person", sa.String(length=40), table=None),"name": sa.Column("name", sa.String(length=40), table=None),"__tablename__": "departments"}'

newStr = re.sub(r',{0,1}\s*table=\w+', '', _str)
print(newStr)
# '{"id": sa.Column("id", sa.Integer(), primary_key=True, nullable=False),"person": sa.Column("person", sa.String(length=40)),"name": sa.Column("name", sa.String(length=40)),"__tablename__": "departments"}'
```

`,{0,1}\s*table=\w+` will match these cases:

1. `, table=abc`
2. `table=abc`
3. `,table=abc`